# SDK JARS for Box.net Integration

Tags: android, performance

I like to integrate Box.Net for cloud access in my android application. I found source code for box-java-sdk-v2 and box-android-sdk-v2 in https://github.com/box. But I would like to have jars for easy integration. Where can i get these jars?

Answer (score 0):

Download box-android-sdk, build it, & then add jars to your app.

Comment: Thanks. I have added both projects in my eclipse and took the boxandroidlibraryv2.jar. But I am unable to use OAuthActivity.BOX_CLIENT which is in box-java-sdk-v2.

Comment: The problem is because it `OAuthActivity` is not a regular class, its an activity(https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk-v2/blob/master/BoxAndroidLibraryV2/src/com/box/boxandroidlibv2/activities/OAuthActivity.java) , and jar file can not include resources, so you need to set box-android-sdk as library project for your app.

Comment: So you want me to include both box-android-sdk-v2 and box-java-sdk-v2 to make it work?

Comment: No, just use jar of java sdk, add it to box-android-sdk & then set only box-android-sdk as a library for your project.

Comment: But from where i can get the jar of java sdk?

Comment: I followed above mentioned steps.But I am getting following error.                           com.box.boxandroidlibv2.activities.OAuthActivity} : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.box.boxandroidlibv2.views.OAuthWebView.setAllowShowingRedirectPage(boolean)' on a null object reference

Comment: I created new question with detailed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589703/box-com-integration-with-an-android-app-oauthactivity-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Box in android (eclipse) then just follow these steps.

1. Download box-android-sdk
2. Download box-java-sdk
3. Now import the two projects in your eclipse
4. Set the box-java-sdk as build path in your box-android-sdk
5. Now set the box-android-sdk as library in your android project